# Python video has no sound when sent from whatsapp

Tags: python, moviepy

I have a specific problem while sending my videos from Whatsapp on an iPhone (everything else works: android, web app on windows and mac). Below you can see my code, every time I send my video from the Whatsapp app on iPhone it appears to be without sound on iPhone devices, I will note that if I send the same video through drive for an example it's working fine.

I will add as well that regular mp4 videos do transfer with sound.
Thanks :)

```
with codecs.open(self.fileName + '.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as stampFile:
  for line in stampFile:
      if self.stop:
          return
      self.counter += 1
      time = line.split(";")
      currStart = timeClass.calculateTimeToSec(time[0])
      currEnd = timeClass.calculateTimeToSec(time[1])
      currStart = max(currStart, 0)
      currEnd = max(currEnd, 0)
      if currEnd <= currStart:
          return
      clip = VideoFileClip(self.mediaFilePath)
      if currStart >= clip.duration:
          return
      currStart = min(currStart, clip.duration - 1)
      currEnd = min(currEnd, clip.duration)
      clip = clip.subclip(currStart, min(currEnd, clip.duration))
      path = self.dirName + "\\BBrief-Clips" + "/BBrief-" + str(self.counter) + "-" + self.mediaFileName
        #threading.Thread(target=lambda: clip.write_videofile(path, codec='libx264')).start()
        clip.write_videofile(path, codec='libx264')
        if prevClip is None:
            prevClip = clip
            clip = fadeout(clip, 1)
        else:
            clip = clip.set_start(prevClip.end)
            clip = fadein(clip, 1)
            clip = fadeout(clip, 1)
            prevClip = clip
        clips.append(clip)
        duration += currStart - currEnd

    path = self.dirName + "\\Singel-BBrief" + "/BBrief-" + self.mediaFileName
    CompositeVideoClip(clips).write_videofile(path, codec='libx264')
    T.sleep(1)
    self.counter += 1
    for clip in clips:
        clip.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this solution by changing the output file to be MOV.

```
path = self.dirName + "mediaFileName"[:-4]+".MOV"
    CompositeVideoClip(clips).write_videofile(path, codec='libx264')
```